# What does it mean when chia seeds are bitter?

Tags: flavor, seeds, raw, chia

I have bough some chia seeds in bulk and when I add liquid their gel have a bitter, almost chemical taste. What does it mean (bad quality? stale?) and how can I get rid of it (if that's safe)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "their gel"?

Comment: @dogwoodtree-dot-net When seeds are soaked they produce gelatinous something - see for example http://allrecipes.com/recipe/222060/chia-gel/ (first link from google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the reason that last bunch were nasty bitter: they can go rancid. I smelled them: OFF! http://www.chiaseedspot.com/do-chia-seeds-go-rancid/

I purchased from bulk and consumed just now.  Yuck!!! I've NEVER had chia with any bitter chemical taste before, and now I must discard a big bag of it bought at a Smart & Final' Superstore's bulk section, on sale at a good price, but sold at 1/2 the normal price because  being so substandard in truth. Wish I had tasted it first, because I didn't save the receipt. :(